# Accessing a hash key as an argument for eval

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have a method

```
def test_eval(formula, num)
   eval(formula)
end
```

Then I can say

```
p test_eval("2 + num", 3)
```

And during the eval process it will see that `num` is defined to be 3 in this context, and will print out 5.

Suppose I wanted to allow arbitrary variable names in my formula. For example, I want to evaluate the formula

```
test_eval("2 + num1 + num2", 3, 5)
```

I can modify the method signature to accept two parameters called `num1` and `num2`, but is there a way for me to, instead of having to hardcode the signature, simply accept a hash of variable names?

For example

```
test_eval("2 + num1 + num2", {:num1 => 3, :num2 => 5})
```

And my method would evaluate the formula and return 10. How can I define a method that would allow me to make this call and return the appropriate result?

Comment: Why do you need to do this at all? I suspect that you've decided that `eval` is the solution and now you're trying to make it work when you might be better off backing up and starting again.

Comment: @muistooshort `eval` was definitely the easiest solution to think of, since I'm interesting in allowing others to pass in formulas of their own along with their own variables within the context of the formula. The formulas can be arbitrary ruby code, as opposed to something specific like a math equation parser.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party (if you really want to party with `eval`):

```ruby
require 'ostruct'
OpenStruct.new({:num1 => 3, :num2 => 5}).instance_eval("2 + num1 + num2") => 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def test_eval(formula, **bindings)
  b = binding
  bindings.each do |var, val| b.local_variable_set(var, val) end

  b.eval(formula)
end

test_eval('2 + num1 + num2', num1: 3, num2: 5)
# => 10
```

I do agree with the others, though: this is not a good idea:

```
test_eval('`rm -rf /` # Oops.')
```

Comment: What if I secure it using `$SAFE`? Would it be better (or not as bad)?

Comment: Not really. `$SAFE` isn't safe. It's an addon, an afterthought. Features such as this have to be built in from the very beginning. There are holes in `$SAFE`. In general, you should not rely solely on the Ruby builtin isolation features, but instead use some isolation outside of Ruby. For example, you could run two instances of IronRuby in two separate AppDomains. Or run two instances of JRuby in separate security contexts. Or run two instances of Rubinius/YARV/whatever in two separate OS processes. Rely on .NET's, Java's or the OS's isolation features instead of (or in addition to) Ruby's.

Comment: If arbitrary users aren't providing input, would eval still be an issue?

Comment: You said: "I'm interesting in allowing others to pass in formulas of their own" and "The formulas can be arbitrary ruby code", that sounds very dangerous. *If* you have complete control over those formulae, *then* it becomes a lot less dangerous … but then again, if you have complete control, maybe there is a way to avoid having to pass around arbitrary strings of Ruby code altogether?

Answer (score 0):

```
def test_eval(formula, params)
   params.each do |key, value|
     formula = formula.gsub(key.to_s,value.to_s)
   end

   eval(formula)
end
```

Comment: What happens when you `test_eval('a + aa', :a => 1, :aa => 2)`? There are a lot of other holes in this approach.